# Automatically add taxonomy term based on state

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Suppose I have a shopping website for a number of shops selling toys. Not each shop sells each toy.

Our solution is that there is a taxonomy 'shops' and toys have a field to assign toys to a particular shop (or multiple shops). This works ok, but has two major flaws:

- I dont want shop owner A to be able to change whether shop B sells a particular toy (they are competitors)
- I dont want shop owners to have to select their shop each time when they add a toy.

So what I want is that upon login, the shop owner gets assigned a particular shop. When adding toys, this shop is automatically being added to the toy's "shops" field.

Furthermore, the site administrator should be able to select a shop upon login, and then see only stuff belonging to that shop.

How to achieve this without writing my own module?

Comment: What have you tried? If you want to control access to taxonomy, it's strange you don't even mention [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access), for example.

Answer (score 0):

some Drupals core features will deal with parts of this for you.

You can set up a Role and set boolean permissions for

'Create own value for'
'Edit own value for field'
'Edit anyone's value for'
'View own value for '
'View anyone's value for

on fields of nodes/entities.

However with a project of this size you should expect to have to get your hands dirty and write code at some point ! IMHO